# What does int foo = bar << '\n'; mean in c++?

Tags: c++

Here is a code that I accidentally write:

```
int bar = 5;
int foo = bar << '\n';
int cnt = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < foo; i++) {
    cnt++;
}
cout << cnt << '\n';
```

Why the `cnt` gives output `5120`. I expected that to be a compilation error.

Comment: What C++ textbook are you learning this from? We are not a replacement for such a resource.

Comment: @NeilButterworth It's not from a c++ book, I accidentally wrote this, it was a typo.

Comment: That wasn't my point - my point was what do you understand by `<<` and what do you understand by ``\n`` - your C++ textbook should explain both.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I use C++ Primer Plus 6th Edition. Is it good for a beginner?

Comment: No, it isn't - it is a very bad book.

Comment: 5th edition was pretty good. It .... wait a sec. *C++ Primer **Plus***? As in not *C++ Primer*? As in not Lippman, Lajoie, and Moo? *C++ Primer* is a good book. *C++ Primer Plus*  I've never even heard of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `'\n'` is a `char` which is just another type of number, and `<<` (although we often see it in its overloaded form with streams) is first-and-foremost a "left shift" operator, which works on two numbers.

So, you have the number `bar` (or 5) and the number `'\n'` (or, assuming ASCII, 10). Here's how they look in two's complement binary:

```
0000 0000 00‭00 0101  (5)
       ^^ ^^^^ ^^^^
         ten bits
```

You shift the 5 left by 10 bits and this gives you...

```
‭0001 0100 0000 0000‬
       ^^ ^^^^ ^^^^
         ten bits
```

…or 5120.

By the way, you could have just printed the value of `foo`, instead of building `cnt` with a loop.

When you see `someStream << '\n'` and it does something totally different, it's because `someStream` is an instance of a class that *overloads* the operator `<<` giving it a new meaning in that context. Yes, it's a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

```
int foo = bar << '\n';
```

Means move bar value 5 which is in binary 0101 '\n' bits left. '\n' is 10 when interpreted as int.

Answer (score 1):

<< is a shift operator for integers. It moves the bits to the left. Basically it multiplies by 2^x.

The \n in singlequotes is a character. Characters are like integers and can be used in arithmetic operations.